# Add a column to a query result in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run in SQL Developer this code,

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID AS NON_MANAGER_EMPLOYEES
FROM EMPLOYEES 
MINUS
SELECT MANAGER_ID 
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Shows:

```
NON_MANAGER_EMPLOYEES
104
107
141
142
143
144
174
176
178
200
202
206
```

Which is what I want. Now I just want to add a column to that so it shows their last name with it. Throwing LAST_NAME onto the select statements:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID AS NON_MANAGER_EMPLOYEES, LAST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES 
MINUS
SELECT MANAGER_ID, LAST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

doesn't work. It tarnished the MINUS. How do I add that information without ruining the MINUS? or rather:

```
NON_MANAGER_EMPLOYEES     LAST_NAME
104                       Ernst
107                       Lorentz
141                       Rajs
...                       ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would appear that you are trying to get a list of employees who aren't managers. So why not get rid of the minus statement and add a where clause. Something like "where manager_id is null"

Comment: `WHERE manager_id IS NULL` would return a list of employees who don't have a manager, as opposed to a list of employees who aren't managers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to `join` the results back to the employee table and use a subquery:

```
SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID, E.LAST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES E
    JOIN (
        SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID
        FROM EMPLOYEES 
        MINUS
        SELECT MANAGER_ID
        FROM EMPLOYEES
    ) E2 ON E.EMPLOYEE_ID = E2.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

---

If I understand you're expected results, here's an alternative approach using `NOT IN`:

```
select employee_id, last_name
from employees e
where employee_id not in (select manager_id from employees)
```

Comment: If the subquery returns a NULL, even one, then that query using `NOT IN` won't return anything. The subquery should read `SELECT manager_id FROM employees WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @DavidFaber -- true and a good point to bring up.  Depends on the table structure.  If it's a non-nullable field, then this should be equivalent to `not exists`.  However, if it's nullable, `not in` and `not exists` can produce different results.  Great comment.

Answer (score 2):

Minus is really the wrong operation here. I would leverage `EXISTS` instead. For example,

```
SELECT employee_id AS non_manager_employees, last_name
  FROM employees e
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT NULL FROM employees m WHERE e.employee_id = m.manager_id)
```

This will filter out any rows where the given employee is also a manager.

Alternatively, you could use this syntax (it does the same thing however).

```
SELECT e.employee_id AS non_manager_employees, e.last_name
  FROM employees e
  LEFT JOIN employees m ON m.manager_id = e.employee_id
 WHERE m.employee_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this out in sql server with EXCEPT KEYWORD it works fine.

```
 SELECT empid 'NonEmployees',  lastname from employeetable
 EXCEPT
 SELECT managerid, lastname 
 FROM employeetable
 where managerid is not null
```

Please use the MINUS keyword instead of EXCEPT and try it in Oracle, also include As to rename the column. let me know.